# DOM Parser will not return string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I have an HTML DOM Parser. It works... sort of. It's trying to get the text from a div which has a class.

See the main file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    #txt_out {
        border: 2px solid #C2C2C2;
        color: #2E2E2E;
        background: #EDEDED;
        width: 97%;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: monospace;
        outline: none;
        height: 800px;
        margin: 10px 0;
      }
  </style>
  <title>Get Ranks</title>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" >   
    $(document).on("click", ".go", function (event) {

        var ID = $(".rank").val();
        console.log("Loading rank: " + ID);
        loadData(ID);


    });


    function loadData(ID) {
        var getRank = ID;

        var dataString = 'getRank=' + getRank;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "otherTest.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {

                $("#txt_out").append(html);

            }
        });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Get Mens Rankings</h1>
    
    <input value="233" class="rank" />
    
    <button class="go">Get stats</button>
    
    <textarea readonly="readonly" id="txt_out"></textarea>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

and upon clicking the 'get stats' button, it calls (through AJAX) this page:

```
<?php
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$rank = $_POST['getRank'];

$URL = "http://fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/gender=m/rank=".$rank."/confederation=25998/page=1/_ranking_table.html";

$html = file_get_html($URL);

$test = trim($html->find('.rnkdate', 0)->innertext);
echo "Date published: " . $test;

?>
```

It's trying to extract the date published from this URL: `http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/gender=m/rank=233/confederation=25998/page=1/_ranking_table.html` where `rank=XXX` is a different table for a different month.

Anyway, when I do this, here's what I get:

[image]

The problem is that it's inside another DIV and thus... I guess it doesn't show inside a `<textarea>`. So... how do I get inside that div and extract the text itself?

Comment: FYI *simple_html_dom* is a **terrible** DOM parser

Comment: Works good enough for me. <shrug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using the http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ , then according to http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm , seems you should be using "plaintext", not "innertext" (as innertext seems to be what javascript devs call innerHTML , while "plaintext" seems to be  the js equivalent of .textContent ... this simplehtmldom lib seems to be written by people who aren't web devs... whatever) anyway

```
$test = trim($html->find('.rnkdate', 0)->plaintext);
```